# Round integer in python without using round()

Tags: python, rounding

I know that I can round to the closest multiple of 10 in python by using `round(<int>, -1)` Is there a way to do this without using this built in function?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the feedback!
The answer using divmod() was interesting because I had never used divmod before. Just in case anyone wants to know on CodingBat the solution used modulo as was suggested in the comments. Here it is in case anyone is interested.

```
def round10(num):
  mod = num % 10
  num -= mod
  if mod >= 5: num += 10
  return num
```

Comment: This sounds like an interview question

Comment: It's not, it is from a practice puzzle on CodingBat.com I was just trying to do it without using the round() function. The puzzle is here http://codingbat.com/prob/p179960

Comment: Could you use [modulo](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divide by `10`, `int`, multiply by `10`.

Actually, you can do it without any builtins using the `//` operator:

```
>>> def round(x):
...     return (x//10)*10
... 
>>> round(15.)
10.0
>>> round(25.)
20.0
```

Of course, this always rounds down.  If you want to round up for values with a remainder greater than 5, you could use `divmod`:

```
def round(x):
    n, remainder = divmod(x, 10)
    if remainder >= 5:
        n += 1
    return n * 10
```

Comment: This won't round to the "closest multiple of 10", though (at least not how I'd interpret that phrase.)

Comment: This is one implementation of rounding (round down) but how would you deal with the more common (in the US at least) of round half up?

Comment: @JasonSperske -- Added that too.

Answer (score 2):

This rounds to the closest, not always up or always down:

```
def xround(n):
    return (n + 5) // 10 * 10
```

Comment: This is clever.  I've seen it used before -- Not sure why I didn't think of it.  I would suggest integer division for python 3 compatability though (and for use with floats).

Answer (score 0):

Round down to the closest multiple of 10:

```
int(n / 10) * 10
```

Round up to the closest multiple of 10:

```
int((n + 10) / 10) * 10
```

Round to the closest multiple of ten:

```
(int(n / 10) + bool(n % 10 >= 5)) * 10
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if whoever downvoted would give a reason for doing so, so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that rounds `n` to the nearest multiple of `d`:

```
def cm(n,d,o="+"):
    p = d - (n % d)
    m = n % d
    nm = n - m
    np = n + p
    if p > m:
        return nm
    elif m > p:
        return np
    else:
        if o == "+":
            return np
        else:
            return nm
```

How to use:
use cm(number, near multiple wanted, preferred direction in special cases)

Examples:

```
cm(8,10) = 10
cm(6,4,"-") = 4 #special case (n % d == d - n % d)
cm(6,4,"+") = 8 #special case
cm(6,4) = 8
```